# Database of Words and their Semantic Entropies?

Tags: semantics, word-sense-disambiguation, entropy

I'm reading up on semantic entropies and it seems as though there aren't any actual databases of words and their associated semantic entropies for any given methodology. For instance, [this study](https://aclanthology.org/W97-0207.pdf) has a great way of calculating them involving translation, but only publishes the semantic entropies for select words and average semantic entropies for each part of speech. Is there anywhere I can find a comprehensive listing of semantic entropies or is my best shot just to email somebody who's compiled them for a particular methodology and ask for their data?